# Using Mat_CreateVer for MATLAB versions higher than 7.3

Tags: matlab, matio

I have a C++ application for Windows platform. This application creates MAT-files. Presently we support only versions 4, 5 and 7.3 of MATLAB. We want to add support for higher MATLAB versions.

In `.h` (downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/matio/), in the enum `mat_ft`, there is support for only three MATLAB versions: 4, 5 and 7.3.

```
enum mat_ft {
    MAT_FT_MAT73  = 0x0200,   /**< @brief Matlab version 7.3 file             */
    MAT_FT_MAT5   = 0x0100,   /**< @brief Matlab version 5 file               */
    MAT_FT_MAT4   = 0x0010,   /**< @brief Matlab version 4 file               */
    MAT_FT_UNDEFINED =   0    /**< @brief Undefined version                   */
```

};

To create a MAT-file while calling `Mat_CreateVer` we pass the above enum

```
pMat = Mat_CreateVer(matFileName.append(".mat").toLocal8Bit().data(), NULL, MAT_FT_MAT73);
```

This is OK for MATLAB versions up to 7.3.
I have to call `Mat_CreateVer()` for MATLAB R2016b and other higher version up to R2023b. What enum value I should pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MAT file versions correspond to the version number of MATLAB when they were introduced. MAT file version 7.3 is good for MATLAB v7.3 (release R2006b) *and later*. The file format has not been changed since (as of R2023b), so that is the still latest. See [this doc page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html) for a list of MAT file versions.

Also note there's a difference between the MATLAB [`version`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/version.html) and the release, returned by [`matlabRelease`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabrelease.html).